# How to convert a CGFloat to an unsigned integer

Tags: iphone, objective-c, stringwithformat, cgfloat

I am trying to get a string using a CGFloat, something like this..

```
helpMessage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"The unsigned integer value is %i", (unsigned int)myCGFloat];
```

This does not want to work. Given a CGFloat value of -2 I am getting 0 for in the string.

If I use...

```
helpMessage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"The unsigned integer value is %i", (int)myCGFloat];
```

I get -2. That's getting closer. So I thought I could use @u as the format specifier but I get 4294967294.

What am I doing wrong.

Thanks in advance for any help. This should be an easy one.

John

Comment: What result are you hoping to get for -2?

Answer (score 3):

You're getting `4294967294` because after converting your value to an `unsigned int`, there isn't a bit that can be used to represent the negativity of `-2`, so the value "underflows" by 2 instead, so to speak:

```
0
4294967295 (-1)
4294967294 (-2)
```

You should be formatting as a signed integer (`%i`) if you want to display negative values. The range of a signed 32-bit integer is `-2147483648` to `2147483647`, while the range of an unsigned 32-bit integer is `0` to `4294967295`.

Answer (score 1):

So you are trying to cast -2 to an unsigned int?  Unsigned int's cant be less than 0. It is thus going to be represented incorrectly.

Answer (score 1):

Ok. Thanks for the answers I figured it out...

```
helpMessage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"The abasolute value is %i", abs((int)myCGFloat]);
```

I had tried abs directly on the CGFloat, but I see now that abs is expecting an int value. I thought an unsigned int was the same thing as an absolute value. Thanks for for setting me straight.

John

Comment: Oooops that should have been ...(abs)(int)myCGFloat;

Comment: Max, thanks. I probably did not know to edit my post when I asked this question over 2 years ago. I am a bit more knowledgeable today, but not by much.